# How would you label an axis that is Log base 10 in Gyr?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

I have a chart that displays conformal time on the vertical axis, comoving distance on the horizontal axis.  The values are in units of billions of years (Gyr), but scaled logarithmically such that $$F(x)=\log_{10}\left(\frac{G(x)}{\text{Gyr}}\right)$$
How would you label this axis?
My first pass: $\text{Conformal Time}(\log_{10}(\text{Gyr}))$ just doesn't look right.

**Edit:** I'm trying to visualize the Horizon problem.  Linear scales leave a little smudge at the bottom where the particle horizon should be.  As per Rob Jefferies suggestion, I change to a logarithmic axis.  Here's the chart so far:

[image]

Comment: I would have expected the bottom tick on your log scale to be labeled 0.1, rather than 0, as in the current plot (v5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\log_{10} ({\rm Conformal\ Time}/{\rm Gyr})$

However, I would plot Conformal Time (Gyr) on a logarithmic axis (which would just be labelled as "Conformal Time (Gyr)" ).

Comment: OK.  You're right.  It does look better on a logarithmic axis.  Does that change how you would label it?

Comment: @GluonSoup Yes! See edit

Answer (score -1):

I would not write units inside a formulae (this is a practice followed in low grade physics treatments, and mathematical nonsense). Also nested brackets are to be avoided where possible. If plotting the variable G on a log scale, I would write Conformal Time, log(G) -- the argument is not needed here, that is on the other axis. The alternative is to write Conformal Time, G, and mark the points on the axis $10^n$ for appropriate values of $n$.